# How to filter returned objects from a many-to-many Doctrine association based on an extra field

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Suppose I want to link two tables: CHILD(ren) to their PARENT(s) with a many-to-many association through a joint table ROLE

In the mapping of the CHILD entity, here is what I would put:

```
/**
  * @var Parent[]|ArrayCollection $parents
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Parent::class, inversedBy="children")
  * @ORM\JoinTable(name="ROLE",
  * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="children_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
  * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")}
  * )
*/
private $parents;
```

and in the PARENT entity :

```
/**
* @var Child[] $children
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Child", mappedBy="parents")
*/
private $children;
```

Now, let's say **I have a discriminating PARENTTYPE field (and a string property M/F)** that lets me know if I'm dealing with the FATHER or the MOTHER (or even two fathers or two mothers).

How should I write the **getMothers() and getFathers() methods** in the CHILD entity?

Is there a way to filter the ROLES collection via a special Doctrine association/annotation or should I "manually" loop over this collection to filter it, based on the $role[i]->getParentType string property?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the getMothers() and getFathers() methods in the CHILD entity as follows:

```
public function getMothers(): array
{
    return $this->parents->filter(function (Parent $parent) {
        return $parent->getType() === ParentType::MOTHER;
    });
}
 
public function getFathers(): array
{
    return $this->parents->filter(function (Parent $parent) {
        return $parent->getType() === ParentType::FATHER;
    });
}
```